# Derivation of the Conformal Ward Identity in Di Francesco et al

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, correlation-functions, ward-identity

I am reading section 5.2.2. (titled *The Conformal Ward Identity*) from Conformal Field Theory by Di Francesco et al. The authors write
\begin{align}
\partial_\mu(\epsilon_\nu T^{\mu\nu}) &= \epsilon_\nu \partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu} + \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \epsilon_\nu + \partial_\nu \epsilon_\mu) T^{\mu\nu} + \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\epsilon_\nu - \partial_\nu \epsilon_\mu) T^{\mu\nu}\notag\\
&= \epsilon_\nu\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu} + \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\rho \epsilon^\rho) \eta_{\mu\nu}T^{\mu\nu} +\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\alpha \epsilon_\beta \varepsilon_{\mu\nu}T^{\mu\nu},\hspace{2cm} \tag{5.42}
\end{align}

where $\varepsilon_{\mu\nu}$ is the antisymmetric Levi-Civita in two dimensions. Then the authors write that the three Ward identities $(5.32)$ derived in section $4.3.2$ can be encapsulated using the above relation as
\begin{equation}
\delta_\epsilon \langle X\rangle  = \int_M d^2 x \partial_\mu\langle T^{\mu\nu} \epsilon_{\nu}(x) X\rangle.\hspace{2cm} \tag{5.44}
\end{equation}
I do not understand how the authors make this statement. Can someone explain it to me? I am clueless here. Thank you.

Edit: For completeness, I include here the Ward identities
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} \langle{T}{^\mu\hspace{0.5mm}_\nu}X\rangle &= -\sum_{i=1}^n \delta(x-x_i)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu_i}\langle X \rangle\\
\varepsilon_{\mu\nu}\langle T^{\mu\nu} X\rangle &= -i\sum_{i=1}^n s_i \delta(x-x_i)\langle X\rangle\\
\langle T^\mu\hspace{0.5mm}_\mu X\rangle &= - \sum_{i=1}^n \delta(x-x_i)\Delta_i \langle X\rangle,\tag{5.32}
\end{align}
where $X$ is a string of primary operators at positions $x_i$ and $s_i$ is the spin of the $i$th field in the string $X$.